# How would I approach a coffee excursion/tour in Ethiopia?

Tags: coffee-culture

I am interested in possibly travelling to Ethiopia next spring/summer and am curious about coffee tours or excursions, what that would look like, and if anyone has done this before. Thanks!

Comment: Everybody wonders, no one knows... :)

Answer (score 2):

I would say reach out to a roaster that you are fond of or have established a relationship with, they would be able to give you pointers.